# breaking the parameters of shell script into several causes errors

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script using a phantom js function

The Phantom JS function crashes when it is run on too many urls apparently, I tried to rewrite it to only do part at a time but I get an error where the $url variable does not change so it always copies down the same url though it appears to write down the actual size of the site.

If I could be helped through that error that would be glorious.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Importing URLs..."
file=sizeurls.csv
url=""
while IFS= read -r line
do
     url+=" "
     url+=$line
done < "$file"
echo "Gathering page sizes..."
phantomjs yslow.js --info basic --format plain $url | grep 'url\|size' > temp.txt
echo "Formatting data..."
sed -i 's/size://g' temp.txt
sed -i 's/url://g' temp.txt
paste - - -d, < temp.txt > pagesize.csv
echo "Done!"
```

version that is supposed to do part at a time, it may be mortally screwed because I just messed with it a little bit an d I am not sure I returned it to the previous state

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Importing URLs..."
file=sizeurls.csv
url=""
i=0;

while  IFS= read -r line  
do

  while [ $i -le 10 ] #10 at a time i < 10
  do
     url+=" "
     url+=$line
     i=$((i+1));

  done < "$file"

phantomjs yslow.js --info basic --format plain $url | grep 'url\|size' >> temp.txt
#echo "Formatting data..."
sed -i 's/size://g' temp.txt
sed -i 's/url://g' temp.txt
paste - - -d, < temp.txt >> pagesize.csv
done < "$file"
i = 0

echo "Done!"
```

Answer (score 1):

This may give you some ideas (untested, but looks about right). The processing is moved to a function where it is called every 10th URL, and again at the end if there are any leftover URLs.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Importing URLs..."
file=sizeurls.csv
rm pagesize.csv

ProcessURLs () {
    echo "Gathering page sizes..."
    phantomjs yslow.js --info basic --format plain $@ | grep 'url\|size' > temp.txt
    echo "Formatting data..."
    sed -i 's/size://g' temp.txt
    sed -i 's/url://g' temp.txt
    paste - - -d, < temp.txt >> pagesize.csv
}


url=""
count=0
while IFS= read -r line
do
    url+="$line$ "
    (( count++ ))
    # Procss URLs in 10-URL chunks
    if [[ $count -ge 10 ]] ; then
        ProcessURLs $url
        url=''
        count=0
    fi
done < "$file"

# Handle any remaining URLs
[ -n "$url" ] && ProcessURLs $url

echo "Done!"
```

Comment: the output is 

0.2K (203 bytes), http://www.kk.com/teas$
0.2K (203 bytes), http://www.kk.com/tesn$

which is worng :l

it is only displaying one site ten times :/

Comment: I just noticed forgot to reset count after it calls the function - should work better now that I've added count=0 there.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do one at a time?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Importing URLs..."
file=sizeurls.csv

echo "Gathering page sizes..."
while IFS= read -r url
do
  phantomjs yslow.js --info basic --format plain $url | grep 'url\|size'
done < "$file" > temp.txt

echo "Formatting data..."
sed -i -e 's/size://g' -e 's/url://g' temp.txt
paste - - -d, < temp.txt > pagesize.csv

echo "Done!"
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but not knowing how phantomjs performs I couldn't rule out an advantage to letting it process "in bulk".